# Do I have to "touch" a waypoint to add it to the waypoint list?

Tags: diablo-iii

In *Diablo II*, you [had to "touch"/click the waypoint](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Waypoint) as if you were using it to "find" it, adding it to your waypoint list. I know that *Diablo III* waypoints [reset based on the quest](http://diablowiki.net/Waypoint#Waypoint_Function), but are waypoints acknowledged automatically upon passing them, or must they be "touched"? If they don't have to be touched, what distance still qualifies as having found the waypoint, and can party members get waypoints for the whole team? Would the whole party get the waypoints even if they weren't there at the waypoint itself, or say, in town while the rest of the party was working through the zone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to actually click on the waypoint -- simply moving close to it is enough to activate it. This is a large visual and audio effect with pulses of blue light and sound, so it's very easy to tell when you have successfully activated a waypoint.

In multiplayer, you can teleport to any other player, so even if activating waypoints *doesn't* unlock them for all active players, all you need to do is teleport to your friend to immediately unlock the waypoint yourself.

Comment: Just adding some extra information: [This blue](http://d3db.com/blue/thread/4662716973/us) and [this one](http://d3db.com/blue/thread/3123245763/us).

Comment: To clarify, can a party member automatically unlock the waypoint for the party, or must you get it individually?

Comment: @sean Following the logic in [this link](http://d3db.com/blue/thread/4662716973/us) "If you want to jump to a later point you need to make **or join a game that begins at that point.**" then YES you can join in a party and it will provide the way point for you (BUT remember, you can't "jump" in quests that you haven't done yet)